# How to present analytics on website redesign?

Tags: analytics

I'm currently redesigning a website from scratch which will replace a new one. Considering that the website is not a e-commerce website, but a website that sells a project, the only conversion metric I have is a request quote form, so I'm unsure on how to measure UX metrics. What would be an ideal framework? Someone asked me to check 3 basic steps (interest, understanding, ready to make a decision) and asking through qualitative research (interviews). I guess time on site, bounce rate (stuff from google analytics) is not actual a good KPI for UX right? Which UX metrics are used for content/marketing websites (not applications) ?

Comment: Who will you be presenting the data to? Stakeholders? What do they care about? They will most likely want know if the new site improves business outcomes. Identify the goals/reasons for redesigning the site. Is it to increase requests for quotes? Learn about your project? Identify the business objectives, then find tools to measure how the website is helping to meet those objectives.

Answer (score 2):

The right metrics depends from the business and UX objectives. I know very little about your site and business, but I would recommend you to consider the following metrics :

**Form unsuccessful completion rate** : How many people visit the request quote form page, compared to how many people succesfuly submit it. This is a very critical metric, because if the ratio is high, it probably means that you have some UX issues with the form or that you are asking too many personal information.

**Path Length** : For your case you do not want a very long path. If the path length is too long it probably means that users are lost, and are trying to figure out how to find the information they want.

**Bounce Rate** : High bounce rate is not good. One way to interpret it, is that the first impression of your site discouraged people from trying to go further. Another explanation for your case, is more business oriented. Users get exactly what they want from they site, they just decide what you offer does not interest them.

**Awareness** : Number of people that visited your site. This is a business metric to measure the effectiveness of the marketing/promotion applied. You may have a perfect site, but if users do not know it exists, it will be useless.